# Relative position on flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, flag-varieties

Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the $G$ diagonal action on $G/B \times G/B$, the orbit is indexed by $W$, the Weyl group of $G$ by Bruhat decomposition. There is a natural map from $G/B \times G/B$ to $G/B$ by projection to the first coordinate. The fiber over each point in the orbit $w$ is an affine space $\mathbb{C}^{l(w)}$.

I have two questions:

1) Is this fibration trivial?

2) Is it naturally a $\mathbb{C}^{l(w)}$-torsor? Namely, do we have a natural $\mathbb{C}^{l(w)}$ action on fiber?

Comment: The answer to both questions is "no".  When $G$ equals $\mathbf{SL}_2$, then $G/B$ equals $\mathbb{P}^1$.  The Bruhat decomposition of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ is equivalent to the partition into the ample divisor $\Delta$ and its open affine complement $U$.  The pushforward by $\text{pr}_1$ of $\mathcal{O}_U$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of algebras with a natural filtration by pole order / zero order at infinity.  The associated subquotients give all invertible sheaves $\mathcal{O}(d)$.  If $U$ were an $\mathbb{A}^1$-torsor over $\mathbb{P}^1$, these would all be $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Here is an easier path to the same conclusion.  Since $H^1(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$ vanishes, every $\mathbb{A}^1$-torsor over $\mathbb{P}^1$ is trivial.  Thus, if $U$ is an $\mathbb{A}^1$-torsor, then there exists a section of $\text{pr}_1:U\to \mathbb{P}^1$.  The image of such a section would be a curve in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ that is disjoint from the ample divisor $\Delta$.  This is absurd.